# Application/XML .NET web service endpoint - how to simulate it to be down

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soa

I have a endpoint of a websevice that we consume with `application/xml` header which it accepts and it returns data for a code we look.

Now our code has all implementations for different type of responses, however, I want to simulate a scenario that the service is down and hence I should test my code for what I implemented when it is down.

I don't know how to simulate a service down, can someone please help me with .net C# code

Comment: Point the end point to something incorrect?

Comment: is this a wcf service?  are you unit testing?  if you are using wcf, there's always a interface contract.  you can mock that and return whatver you want.

Comment: if you are integration testing do what sayse says.  if your trying to do unit testing mock it out like i said.

Comment: @Fran: Thank you, it is integration and it is not WCF service.

Comment: @Sayse: apologize, could you please provide me a quick example?

Comment: `endpoint = "thiswebsitedoesntexist.com"` (although it would appear that that url example would return a 200 so pick something else)

Comment: @Sayse: I vaugley understand, let me try what you say :) Thank you so much cheers,